# How is "Haigh's" pronounced in "Haigh's Chocolates"?

Tags: pronunciation

How is *Haigh's* pronounced here?

> [image: Haigh's Chocolates]

I looked up *Haigh* in the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, and I found two entries:

> *Haigh* (placename) /heɪ/
>   *Haigh* (family name) /heɪg/

So based on this, it seems like *Haigh's* could be either /heɪz/ or /heɪgz/, but I'm not sure.  It seems to be an Australian brand, and I've never heard anyone say it before.

Could anyone tell me how *Haigh's* is pronounced in this context?

Comment: I guess the easy answer would be to call them up and see how they pronounce it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the founder's name Alfred Haigh and is pronounced /heig/, which you may check up on YouTube typing *Alfred Haigh* in the search box.